# using for-loop to remove maximum and minimum values from a dictionary

Tags: for-loop, iteration

how can I use for loop to delete maximum and minimum values from a dictionary. for instance if you have a dictionary grades = {sam: [23,43,55]}, peter: [66,55,44], sarah: [99,55,77]}. how can I remove only the maximum and minimum values?
im new to coding and cannot figure it out. Language is python

Comment: What language? It looks a bit like Python, but there's no quotes around the keys? What result do you expect for the given example? What have you tried at all? Being new and asking beginner's questions is fine, but don't expect StackOverflow to write your code for you. Share what you tried so people can start at your level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi you can try something like this:

```py
  # Create dictionary
  dic = {'sam': [23,43,55], 'peter': [66,55,44], 'sarah': [99,55,77]}

  # Use for loop to iterate
  for key, value in dic.items():
      # Find maximum value and it's index
      max_value = max(value)
      max_index = value.index(max_value)

      # Delete maximum value
      del dic[key][max_index]
      
      # Find minimum value and it's index
      min_value = min(value)
      min_index = value.index(min_value)

      # Delete miniumum value
      del dic[key][min_index]

  # Print output
  print(dic)
```

Let me know if you don't understand anything. Cheers

Comment: Hi Saad thank you so much for your help. It seemed to work but i am going through your coding to understand how it worked. I literally just started a cybersecurity class and im too embarrassed to even share what i tried. thanks so much again

Comment: Hi @King, you are welcome. Don't worry about sharing the issues you are facing. Stack overflow community is happy to help. Please support by upvotes. And do share if you further face any issues, cheers.